# good way to insert into observable array in knockout using jQuery

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am trying to load in my JSON file and then make an insert for each item.

so I have this code

```
function ProductType(id, name) {
var self = this;

self.id = id;
self.name = name;
}


function ProductsViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    var jqxhr = $.getJSON("data/product.json").success(function(data, status, xhr) { 
          self.products = ko.observableArray([    
      $.each(data.data.productTypeList, function(i,item){
          new ProductType(i, item.longName);
    })
]);               
      })
     .error(function() { alert("error"); })
     .complete(function() {
        console.log("fetch complete + " + this);
     });

}
```

I wondered how best practice to insert into an observable array from an each function

at the current time I get this error

Error: 500 Error get /knockoutJQMProducts/#products Unable to parse bindings.
Message: ReferenceError: products is not defined;
Bindings value: foreach: products

but if i console.log(i) within the each statement it returns the results.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ryadavilli's answer is good, but could be improved by caching the array and then setting the observableArray all at once.

```
function ProductsViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.products = ko.observableArray();
    var jqxhr = $.getJSON("data/product.json").success(function(data, status, xhr) {
        var products = [];
        $.each(data.data.productTypeList, function(i, item) {
            products.push(new ProductType(i, item.longName));
        });
        self.products(products);
    })
        .error(function() {
            alert("error");
        })
        .complete(function() {
            console.log("fetch complete + " + this);
        });
}
```

Comment: Good point. This does reduce the number of notifications that knockout sends on array change.

Answer (score 2):

I have modified your VM and the success method so that the observable array is populated on success. But it exists all the time.

```
function ProductsViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.products = ko.observableArray();    
    var jqxhr = $.getJSON("data/product.json").success(function(data, status, xhr) { 
      // use this remove all only if you want to clear and load with new data.
       self.products.removeAll();
       $.each(data.data.productTypeList, function(i,item){
          self.products.push(new ProductType(i, item.longName));
     })
  })
 .error(function() { alert("error"); })
 .complete(function() {
    console.log("fetch complete + " + this);
 });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. one wierd thing that happens now is that my jQuery Mobile styling doesnt happen for those items where as it did when I just used 

     self.products = ko.observableArray([
   new ProductType('1','dan'),
   new ProductType('2','s')
   ]);
any ideas why?

Comment: Can you please share your HTML binding code as well ? Also, please check the objects that are getting created within the success call? Is it possible that you or I have missed some property. Also, I see that your object (each ProductType) within the array has all properties as string. Is this the same case with your ajax data? If not you might want to change your bindings or the properties in the ProductType return value to reflect this.

Comment: here is the url

http://demo.stg.brightonconsulting.net.au/templates/tests/knockoutJQMProducts/

note that when you first go through this its ok, but if you refresh the products page it loses stying.. also if I try on my mobile the second page data doesnt even appear!

Comment: @Dan, you seemed to missed posting the URL. Can you also check for the other items i mentioned in my comment above and let me know?

Comment: here is the url

http://demo.stg.brightonconsulting.net.au/templates/tests/knockoutJQMProducts/

note that when you first go through this its ok, but if you refresh the products page it loses stying.. also if I try on my mobile the second page data doesnt even appear! (seems to be a safari issue) again didnt happen when had just the self.products = ko.observableArray([ new ProductType('1','dan'), new ProductType('2','s') ]);

Comment: I was unable to look through the code in detail. But can you try this bit and let me know the outcome. 'self.products.push(new ProductType(i.toString(), item.longName));'

Comment: thanks will try.. really appreciate the help.. sorry to send a link

Comment: no that didnt work.. I think its to do with the time its taking to read the json file and output back to the screen the page has already finished rendering

Comment: Yes, but when your ajax call completes and your success function adds the items into your observable array, you should see the data (with our without formatting, this can be checked later once we have the data). Can you try debugging to see if the ajax call completes, and with a success, and that in the each loop, you have the correct code for example if data.data.productTypeList is correct or may need some tweaking. or, if each item does contain the longname, and it is correct

Comment: I see the data always. just depends if i reload or navigate to the page

if you want to see the code i have added it to this ticket 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13469143/jquery-mobile-force-change-page-on-reload-jqm-knockout-sammy-knockout-load